# Fetch table header for use as row data-label using PHP

Tags: php, html-table

How can I retrieve each respective table header `$col` for use as each rows data label?

```
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <?php foreach ( $t[ 0 ] as $col ): ?>
            <th>
                <?php echo $col; ?>
            </th>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
    <?php foreach ( $t as $idx => $row ): ?>
        <?php if ( $idx == 0 )
            continue; ?>
        <tr>
            <?php foreach ( $row as $col ): ?>
                    <td data-label="<?php Need to retrieve "th" col here ?>">
                    <div>
                        <?php echo str_replace( '"', '&quot;', $col ) ?>                                
                    </div>
                </td>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is a sample of `var_dump(t)`:

```
array(3) { [0]=> array(6) { [0]=> string(11) "Part Number" [1]=> string(3) "CED" [2]=> string(3) "CEL" [3]=> string(5) "SHANK" [4]=> string(3) "OAL" [5]=> string(3) "CUT" } [1]=> array(6) { [0]=> string(11) "SCODSS-140A" [1]=> string(6) "1/4″" [2]=> string(6) "3/4″" [3]=> string(6) "1/4″" [4]=> string(8) "2-1/2″" [5]=> string(7) "Downcut" } [2]=> array(6) { [0]=> string(11) "SCOUSS-140A" [1]=> string(6) "1/4″" [2]=> string(6) "3/4″" [3]=> string(6) "1/4″" [4]=> string(8) "2-1/2″" [5]=> string(5) "Upcut" } }
```

Desired HTML output. Note, the column headers have been populated as data-labels:

```
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
                            <th>
                Part Number                    </th>
                            <th>
                CED                    </th>
                            <th>
                CEL                    </th>
                            <th>
                SHANK                    </th>
                            <th>
                OAL                    </th>
                            <th>
                CUT                    </th>
                    </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
                                                    <tr>
                                    <td data-label="Part Number">
                    <div>
                        SCODSS-140A                             
                    </div>
                </td>
                                    <td data-label="CET">
                    <div>
                        1/4″                                
                    </div>
                </td>
                                    <td data-label="CEL">
                    <div>
                        3/4″                                
                    </div>
                </td>
                                    <td data-label="SHANK">
                    <div>
                        1/4″                                
                    </div>
                </td>
                                    <td data-label="OAL">
                    <div>
                        2-1/2″                              
                    </div>
                </td>
                                    <td data-label="CUT">
                    <div>
                        Downcut                             
                    </div>
                </td>
                            </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                    <td data-label="Part Number">
                    <div>
                        SCOUSS-140A                             
                    </div>
                </td>
                                    <td data-label="CET">
                    <div>
                        1/4″                                
                    </div>
                </td>
                                    <td data-label="CEL">
                    <div>
                        3/4″                                
                    </div>
                </td>
                                    <td data-label="SHANK">
                    <div>
                        1/4″                                
                    </div>
                </td>
                                    <td data-label="OAL">
                    <div>
                        2-1/2″                              
                    </div>
                </td>
                                    <td data-label="CUT">
                    <div>
                        Upcut                               
                    </div>
                </td>
                            </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you show a little sample from `var_dump($t)`, and an example of the HTML you're trying to produce?

Comment: Updated question with var_dump and HTML.

Comment: Looping over all values again in the place where you want to output the label is rather nonsense. Change the outer loop to `foreach ( $row as $idx2 => $col ):`, so that you can access the header value corresponding to the current column index via `$t[ 0 ][ $idx2 ]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inner foreach loop isn't needed at all. As you iterate the columns in each row, you can use the numeric index of that column to refer to the corresponding index in your first row to get the column header value.

```
<?php foreach ( $row as $colIndex => $colValue ): ?>
    <td data-label="<?= $t[0][$colIndex] ?>">
        <div><?= htmlspecialchars($colValue) ?></div>
    </td>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Also, `str_replace` isn't sufficient to escape your output for an HTML document. You should use `htmlspecialchars` instead.